# can't get wxHaskell to work from ghci on Mac

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, macos-carbon, nsundomanager, wxhaskell

I'm trying to run [an example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/Quick_start#Hello_world_in_wxHaskell) using `EnableGUI` [function](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/Building_on_MacOS_X#Using_wxHaskell_on_MacOS_X_platforms).

```
% ghci -framework Carbon Main.hs

*Main> enableGUI >> main
```

This is what I get instead of a working program:

```
2013-01-14 00:21:03.021 ghc[13403:1303] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-945.11/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:328
2013-01-14 00:21:03.022 ghc[13403:1303] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
2013-01-14 00:21:03.024 ghc[13403:1303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c8ea0a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff867243f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c8e9ee8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff884966a2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff884fc8b7 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ecb832d -[NSApplication run] + 687
    6   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-2.9.4.0.0.dylib 0x000000010ae64c96 _ZN14wxGUIEventLoop5DoRunEv + 40
    7   libwx_baseu-2.9.4.0.0.dylib         0x000000010b37e0e5 _ZN13wxCFEventLoop3RunEv + 63
    8   libwx_baseu-2.9.4.0.0.dylib         0x000000010b2e91bf _ZN16wxAppConsoleBase8MainLoopEv + 81
    9   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-2.9.4.0.0.dylib 0x000000010ae1b04f _ZN5wxApp5OnRunEv + 29
    10  libwx_baseu-2.9.4.0.0.dylib         0x000000010b32e8d1 _Z7wxEntryRiPPw + 102
    11  libwxc.dylib                        0x000000010bc8a9a4 ELJApp_InitializeC + 116
    12  ???                                 0x000000010beb9702 0x0 + 4494956290
)
2013-01-14 00:21:03.024 ghc[13403:1303] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-945.11/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:328
```

When I'm compile and `macosx-app` it, it works rather well, but, for obvious reasons, I really want this to work from `ghci`.

What can I do? Google reveals nothing about the misterious problems of `NSUndoManager` used with Haskell. :(

Answer (score 4):

ghci -fno-ghci-sandbox

works for me on OSX 10.8 , wx 0.90.0.1

thanks to Heinrich  :https://github.com/jodonoghue/wxHaskell/pull/6

Comment: adding `ghc-options: -fno-ghci-sandbox` in the cabal file / (Executable section) make is work in Leksah / ghci - debugger too.

Comment: Just tried and confirmed `ghc-options: -fno-ghci-sandbox` solves the problem. Thanks Luc Taesch!

Answer (score 0):

wxHaskell hasn't worked within ghci for a while. Apparently C++ memory management and re-using components within ghci causes problems. You juat have to rewrite main repeatedly. :(

The [faq](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/FAQ) says

> GHCi cannot mix static and dynamic libraries; it will be solved in the near future in wxHaskell.